# SQLAlchemy revert auto_increment during testing (pytest)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest

I use the `db_session` fixture in `conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db_session(db, request):
    """Creates a new database session for a test."""
    engine = create_engine(DefaultConfig.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, connect_args={"options": "-c timezone=utc"})
    DbSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DbSession()

    connection = engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

    db.session = session

    yield session

    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
    session.remove()
```

in my test script `test_project.py`

```
import pytest
from package.model import Project

def test_create_project(db_session):
    project = Project(project_name="Test_Project")

    db_session.add(project)
    db_session.commit()

    assert project.project_id > 0
    assert project.project_id == 65 # supposed to be the next auto-increment value
    assert db_session.query(Project).filter_by(project_name="Test_Project").first() != None
```

Every time I run the test, the auto-incremented primary key will be increased. Even though I use the `db_session` fixture, the primary key sequence does not get rolled-back.

I also tried calling `db_session.begin_nested()` and `db_session.rollback()` in between the test, but the primary key still gets incremented

```
def test_create_project(db_session):
    db_session.begin_nested()
    project = Project(project_name="Test_Project")

    db_session.add(project)
    db_session.commit()

    assert project.project_id > 0
    assert project.project_id == 65
    assert db_session.query(Project).filter_by(project_name="Test_Project").first() != None
    db_session.rollback()
```

How can I revert the auto-increment value after testing?

### Environment

- Database: PostgreSQL 9.6.5
- Flask 0.12.2
- SQLAlchemy 1.1.12

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible using sqlalchemy. However, you can alter & restart the sequence at the desired start point. By default postgresql will name sequences as `<table_name>_<column_name>_seq`. Check your schema to find out the sequence name. It is needed for altering the sequence.

Here's a small script to illustrate this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(col1 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, val TEXT);
INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('abc'), ('def'), ('ghi');
SELECT * FROM test;
-- output
1   abc
2   def
3   ghi

DELETE FROM test WHERE col1 = 3;
SELECT * FROM test;
-- output
1   abc
2   def

-- now alter the sequence so that the next insert gets value 3 in col1
ALTER SEQUENCE test_col1_seq START 3 RESTART;
INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('xyz');
SELECT * FROM test;
-- output
1   abc
2   def
3   xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session.execute('''ALTER SEQUENCE <table name>_<column name>_seq RESTART WITH <reset id>;''')
```

Try setting the reset id to reflect correctly.

Reference : https://brianchildress.co/reset-auto-increment-in-postgres/